# Internet Explorer border adds space

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, whitespace

Internet Explorer 11 adds space in a way I do not understand. In the element below it adds white space on left border.
[Link to a page that illustrates the problem showing how element is displayed in different browsers](http://procyb.com/cssborder.htm)

This is the code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:330px;left:30px;top:120px;visibility:visible;border:1px solid black">
  <div style="position:relative;height:14px;background-color:#B02C2A;padding:6px 0 6px 8px;color:white;"><span>hejsan</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Removing positioning absolute or the border attribute makes the problem disappear, but I need these features. Is there anything I'm missing or is it a bug?

Comment: Not reproduceable. No white space appears inside the box in IE 11 when testing with the code in the question (or viewing the linked page, where the code is different, without some space characters).

Comment: Strange, in my case it certainly shows up. My version of Internet Explorer is 11.0.9600.17501 on Win7, you have a later version/OS?

Comment: I have exactly the same version, on Win 7 Pro (32 bits), SP 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:330px;left:30px;top:120px;visibility:visible;border:1px solid black">
  <div style="position:relative;height:14px;background-color:#B02C2A;padding:6px 0 6px 8px;color:white;"><span>hejsan</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

apply `background-color:#B02C2A;` to the first div, that way it won't show the white spacing of the div

Comment: Gerwin, thanks for your suggestion, it works. When posting my question I scaled down the actual case I'm working with to the main problem. In the specific case I have more divs inside the bottom one and of different color so in that context your suggestion wont work.  It seems the only solution is setting the borders in the inner elements.

Comment: If you could make a jsfiddle, I'm willing to take a look at it for you